# Does the TeX lion mascot have a name?

Tags: tex-history

Duane Bibby drew a lion for the *TeXBook*.

https://www.ctan.org/lion/?lang=en

[image]

Does the lion have a name?

Comment: `Panthera Leo Scribus`

Comment: I don't know but Moggie sounds good to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would have to dig out the old mails, but IIRC Knuth calls the mascots

1. *TeX* the lion
2. *Meta* the lioness
3. *Mixx* was suggested for the computer

Comment: FWIW: I did a google search for those terms and found [this from you](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb19-1/tb58schroder.pdf), [related merchandising project](http://www.dream.kn-bremen.de/tex/merchandising/), and [this](https://www.fiee.net/en/fiee-globale/fiee-texnique/) and [this](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2005/011613.html) by H. Ramm. [This interview with Duane Bibby](https://www.tug.org/interviews/bibby.html) just mentions lions ("the lion character"—Bibby, "the TeX lions"—interviewer) without names as such.